# Connect to SMTP relay in Azure VM with O365 Account fails

Tags: azure, smtp, jakarta-mail, azure-virtual-machine

How can I use from a VM (linux) where a Java application is running a SMTP Server/relay?

For connecting to SMTP I want to use an O365 account, so configuration looks like:

- host: smtp.office365.com
- port: 587
- TLS: true
- uid: UID-O365
- pwd: PWD-O365

As response I get: 
An error has occurred with sending the test email:

```
MailException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:
501 5.1.7 Invalid address [AM4P190MB0211.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address 
[AM4P190MB0211.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

*remark:* The application that wants to connect runs on java, what is probably unimportant

Answer (score 2):

The server is telling you that the address "AM4P190MB0211.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM" that you're using in your message as a sender or recipient address is not a valid email address.  It at least needs a "@" in there somewhere.  You can get more detail in the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: sender email address (what was not listed above) and UID must be the same